# Aws Route 53 - How to keep sub-domains in multiple aws accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

We purchased a domain "company.com" through GoDaddy(managed by my company) and configured the DNS for same domain in my aws account aws-dev.
I created a sub-domain in aws-dev, "sales.dev.company.com" using a public hosted zone and configured required Route 53 entries.
I am to able to access this sub-domain successfully.
Now we have got another aws account aws-test, and we want to transfer the DNS (for company.com) to this account
but want to keep sub-domain/hosted zone for sales.dev.company.com in aws-dev only as services are running in this account.

Is there a way i can transfer the dns for company.com to aws-test and whenever
a request comes in for sales.dev.company.com, it gets routed to another aws account aws-dev in this case which hosts mapped service and otherwise all requests for company.com will be serviced from aws-test account ? If yes how this can be achieved ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/530415/what-is-dns-delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around this solution worked for me:

1. Created hosted zone company.com in aws-test
2. Updated GoDaddy to replace DNS servers to new dns servers from step-1
3. Deleted company.com hosted zone from aws-dev.
4. Create sales.dev.company.com hosted zone in aws-dev.
5. Update ns records from step-4 in company.com in aws-test.

In simple terms this is what happens - whenever a request is being made to sales.dev.company.com, it first go to GoDaddy which forward it to aws-test which own company.com and now because aws-test knows where sales.dev.company.com lives, it gets forwarded to aws-dev.